# Algorithm: Optimisation of connectors

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Suppose there are `n` distinct points in the 3D space, namely `P1, P2, P3, ..., Pn`.

Define a connector, `C`, as a ordered set of line segments, where the next element in the set should share a common vertex with the previous one. For example, `{ P1-P2, P2-P4, P4-P7 }` is a connector, while `{ P1-P2, P3-P4,P4-P2 }` is not.

Define the content of the connector, as the set of points which the connector includes.

Define the magnitude of the connector, to be the length of the longest single segment in the connector.

Define the connector to be a proper connector if the longest single segment is the first or the last segment in the connector.

A set of points are said to be connected if the union of contents of the connectors over the points is the set of points.

The problem is:

Given that `k` proper connectors (`k < n`) of the same magnitude `m` are allowed to connect the `n` points, whose coordinates are given, minimise `m`.

What should the gist of the algorithm be? I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Can edges be revisited within the same connector, possibly in the same direction? Like `a->b->c->b->d->a->b->e`?

Comment: It cannot. Supposedly a connector shall have no repeated vertex.

Comment: does the order matters? can I connect `{P1P5,P5P2,P2P3}` for example?

Comment: Do you have a set of connectors, or do you need to create connectors as well?

Comment: @A.Sarid Sure you can.

Comment: @David connectors can be created freely

Comment: Which points on one connector (call it C1), if any, could be shared by another connector (C2)? For example, could the last point on C1 be the first point on C2? The rules don't seem to contradict that. Could a middle point on C1 be the first or last or middle point on C2? Could C2 and C1 share more than one point?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Do note that if you let the start of C2 coincide with end of C1, you lose one available connector for use and m cannot be minimized. Since the task is to get the points connected, it is trivial to study whether two proper connectors can share points or not, as it is the Union of contents that matters.

Comment: @user122049 thank you for explaining. Just to be precise, though, defining the characteristics of a "Connector," does not necessarily imply that we are not allowed to arbitrarily choose which points to include in any one connector. Under the current rules, without your comment, we could say, {p1p2,p2p3} is one connector and {p3p4,p4p5} is another different connector.

Comment: Is it true that if a single proper connector visits all points, the solution is found for that particular value of m (not yet minimised)? I reason that for any k < n, subseries of this one connector can be counted for the other k-1 needed connectors. Like if you have `a->b->c->d->e->f`, with `a-b` the largest edge, then also these are proper connectors: `a->b`, `a->b->c`, `a->b->c->d`, `a->b->c->d->e`. Or is there a rule that forbids this?

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to start with the most remote point, i.e. its nearest neighbor is the farthest compared to other point's neighbors. Then build a connector from that, always adding the nearest neighbor of the next point, until you cannot add any more points without breaking one of these rules:

- A connector cannot have loops (a point can only be visited once)
- A proper connector cannot have an edge that is larger than the first one

NB: The last condition is too strong, because the last edge of a proper connector could be allowed to be larger than the first, but I take into account that the algorithm would also do another try with such a "last" edge as the first edge, but in the opposite direction: so I can exclude that edge in this phase.

Once such proper connector is found, the algorithm could backtrack and try to branch off in another direction, again going as far as possible. This recursive branching will lead to a set of proper connectors. If that set has at least k connectors, and all points are covered by at least one such connector, then this is a solution.

If this does not work out, the whole logic could be repeated, but this time the first edge must have a larger size. So a point would be found where the distance to its nearest neighbor, having at least that distance, is maximised.

Here is a bit more formal sketch for such an algorithm:

```
Pre-processing:
    List for each point all the other points in order of increasing distance from it.

    set m = 0

Repeat:
    set max_dist = 0, list = empty
    For each point p:
        Find the first neighbor q for which distance(p,q) > m
        if distance(p,q) >= max_dist:
            if distance(p,q) > max_dist:
                clear list
            append (p,q) to the list

    let m = max_dist
    For each pair (p,q) in the list (all these pairs have same distance m):
        Let result = []
        Let connector be [p,q]
        Let p = q

        Recursive part (p):
            let end_point = True
            For each neighbor q of p (in order of distance):
                If distance(p,q) > m: 
                    break loop
                If q not in connector:
                    let end_point = False
                    Append q to connector
                    Call the recursive part for q
                    size(result) >= k and all points are in result:
                        exit recursion
                    Remove q from connector (backtracking)

            If end_point:
                append clone of connector to result

        If size(result) >= k and all points are in result:
            return m, as final result
```

Comment: Why do you choose to add the nearest neighbor each time, rather than just any neighbor not farther than the first segment?

Comment: You right,  @גלעדברקן, they should all be considered, but I think I do so in the pseudo-code at `For each neighbor q of p` within the recursive part.

Answer (score 0):

Some general thoughts. There's probably multiple solutions to your problem. I would start by considering a brute force approach, then consider if we can improve over that algorithm. Another good approach is to find a similar problem that is easier to solve and try to convert this into the similar problem. I won't touch on correctness and time complexity since you don't in the question.

**Brute force** typically means to try every combination. Build every possible chain of connections that covers all nodes.

**A greedy algorithm**: Start with a random node. Create a connector to the closest node. Then create a connector from that node to its closest node, that hasn't been connected yet. Repeat until all all nodes are connected. This will probably not always give optimal results.

**An iterative approach**: Connect all nodes using any method. Then try to swap nodes. Select the node B that has connectors with the highest magnitude and Q randomly, with connectors AB,BC and PQ,QR. Produce AQ,QC and PB,BR and keep the swap if their magnitude decreases.

Maybe it's possible to use **linear programming**.